# Display question with 3 options for quiz with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am working on a project where I have a database filled with questions/options. Each question has 3 options (1 of them is right).
Before a user starts a quiz he selects how many questions he wants to have. I do this with a select form. PHP then sends value from select form to the quiz page. Where it's used in SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM quiz_question
WHERE quiz_id = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT $number
```

The `$number` stands for value of select form
I can display questions but not options for the selected question.
My code:

```
<div id="quiz">
  <?php
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM quiz_question
    WHERE quiz_id = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT $number";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<p>";
      echo $row['question'];
      echo "</p>";
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

My database looks something like this:

**`quiz`**

- `id` (PK)
- `quiz_name` (text)

**`quiz_question`**

- `id` (PK)
- `quiz_id` (FK)
- `question` (text)

**`quiz_question_option`**

- `id` (PK)
- `quiz_question_id` (FK)
- `quiz_option` (text)
- `is_correct` (enum 0, 1)

**EDIT:**
I tried to use `INNER JOIN` but when I used `ORDER BY RAND()` and `LIMIT` I couldn't get all 3 options for a single question.

Comment: you need to use a join statement

Comment: I tried to use join statment but i only get 1 option for 1 question not 3 options for 1 question

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use whitelist for your limit clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put aside SQL injection issue (you should use prepared statement), here is how you can use a secondary query to get all the options of the quiz for rendering.

```php
<div id="quiz">
  <?php

    // aggregate an array of options
    $option_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT qo.* FROM quiz_question_option qo
        LEFT JOIN quiz_question q ON (qo.quiz_question_id = q.id)
        WHERE q.quiz_id = 1");
    $options = [];
    while ($option = mysqli_fetch_assoc($option_results)) {
        $options[$option['quiz_question_id']] = $option;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($option_results);

    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz_question WHERE quiz_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $number";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
         while ($question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo "<p>";
             echo $question['question'];
             echo "</p>";
         }

         if (isset($options[$question['id']])) {
             echo "<ul>";
             foreach ($options[$question['id']] as $option) {
                 echo $option['quiz_option'];
             }
             echo "</ul>";
         }
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Now, to convert to prepared statements:

```php
<div id="quiz">
  <?php
    $number = $_POST['number'] ?? 10000;
    $quiz_id = 1;

    // aggregate an array of all questions' options of a quiz
    $option_stmts = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT qo.* FROM quiz_question_option qo
        LEFT JOIN quiz_question q ON (qo.quiz_question_id = q.id)
        WHERE q.quiz_id = ?");
    $option_stmts->bind_param('i', $quiz_id);
    $option_results = $option_stmts->execute();
    $options = [];
    while ($option = mysqli_fetch_assoc($option_results)) {
        $options[$option['quiz_question_id']] = $option;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($option_results);
    mysqli_stmt_close($option_stmts);

    // query for all the questions of a quiz
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz_question WHERE quiz_id = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $quiz_id, $number);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
         while ($question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             echo "<p>";
             echo $question['question'];
             echo "</p>";
         }

         if (isset($options[$question['id']])) {
             echo "<ul>";
             foreach ($options[$question['id']] as $option) {
                 echo $option['quiz_option'];
             }
             echo "</ul>";
         }
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I get a Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool. On line 35

Comment: Which line is line 35 in your source file?

Comment: $option_stmts->bind_param('i', $quiz_id);

Comment: Please add a `exit(mysqli_error($conn));` call before this line and see what it says.

Comment: Updated my code to prevent running 2 queries in parallel. Please test again and see if it works now.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: stmt  (at the first SQL query)

Comment: Typo in the code, should be `$option_stmts` instead of `$stmts` on that line. Updated my code. Please try again.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool (line 40 second SQL QUERY)$stmt->bind_param('ii', $quiz_id, $number);

Comment: Again, can you put a `exit(mysqli_error($conn));` before that line?

Comment: Strange, I've already used `mysqli_free_result($option_results);`.

Comment: Added  `mysqli_next_result($conn);` after free result. Please try again.

Comment: same error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Please add a  `var_dump($options);` after the while loop and see if the first query works.

Comment: Updated to add `mysqli_stmt_close($option_stmts);`. Please see if this helps.

Comment: I'm getting 3 warnings now: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result ////// mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result ////// mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

Comment: My time is up. Please check the variables one by one to see which is the problem.